# Simple way to encrypt file via Swift and Cocoa?

Tags: swift, file, cocoa, encryption, aes

I am searching for a way to encrypt a file via AES using Swift in my Cocoa Applications.
As far as I can see the common frameworks (i.e. CryptoSwift) are supposed to encrypt text only.
Is there a specific framework for this job or is there any kind of macOS built in method for this?

Thanks!

Comment: *The common frameworks (i.e. CryptoSwift)* can handle `String` and `Data`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using CommonCrypto is a good start. I would not recommend using any homegrown implementations however.

Doing security right is hard, AES is no exception to this.

- You need to use a proper key of the correct length ( 64 or 32 bytes preferred )
- You need to use padding ( I recommend PKCS7 ) in case your data is shorter than the blocksize / keysize. AES is not secure on its own and this bit is important.
- You also really want to use an initializationVector, ( either appendend or prepended to the final data stream ) since otherwise it would be possible for an attacker to draw correlations between several encrypted streams from the same key
- You should also make use of a HMAC ( SHA2-256 and up, also available in commoncrypto ) in order to prevent tampering with your encrypted data and giving you unexpected and potentially harmful result data.

The list goes on, but my memory fails me at this point since It has been a while since I needed to create an implementation.
I would highly recommend googling around for a standard implementation that wraps around CommonCrypto.

I would also suggest that using anything that is written as is ( I.E. CryptoSwift ) is not recommended as the codebase isn't proven and went through proper vetting like Apple's frameworks **are**.